# cocoahttpserver - disaply file

Tags: share, nsdocumentdirectory, cocoahttpserver

I try to use cocoaHttpServer for display my document's folder files with pc/mac browser, I use iPhoneHTTPServer sample example, I change root directory but I don't see any file.
This is my code:

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
httpServer = [[HTTPServer alloc] init];     
[httpServer setType:@"_http._tcp."];
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
[httpServer setDocumentRoot:documentsDir];
[self startServer];
```

I need to create an index file?but in this case for refresh the index content I need to refresh from device and not from browser...any tip?

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
            <title>DPFileUpload</title>
            </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8"> Select a file to upload :
            <input type="file" name="upload1"><br/> <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

and `upload.html` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
            </head>
    <body>
        %MyFiles%
    </body>
</html>
```

These need to be in your webserver documents directory.
I have not found a way to enhance it (look nicer) and provides just a basic implementation. A working one at least.